# gstreamer receive and reassamble h.264 video over udp

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, h.264

I'm trying to capture a video stream from a Tello drone with `gstreamer`

I've tried with a `gstreamer` pipeline of

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc buffer-size=622080 skip-first-bytes=2 port=6038 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)RAW,width=(string)960, height=(string)720, payload=(int)96, a-framerate=25" \
    ! queue \
    ! rtpvrawdepay \
    ! autovideosink
```

But this outputs (with `export GST_DEBUG=*:3`)

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpVRawDepay:rtpvrawdepay0: Could not decode stream.
Additional debug info:
gstrtpbasedepayload.c(506): GstFlowReturn gst_rtp_base_depayload_handle_buffer(GstRTPBaseDepayload *, GstRTPBaseDepayloadClass *, GstBuffer *) (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpVRawDepay:rtpvrawdepay0:
```

Information about the stream can be seen here: https://github.com/m6c7l/dji-ryze-tello/tree/master/example/video

The video can be piped into `ffmpeg` with the following command `ffmpeg -i - -f image2pipe -pix_fmt rgb24 -vcodec rawvideo -`

I'm missing a `gstreamer` pipeline that can piece these NALs together into a h264 frame.

## Update: output with `playbin`

I tried running the command with `export GST_DEBUG=*:3` and I'm getting the following output repeatedly:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=udp://0.0.0.0:6038
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: ring-buffer-max-size = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-size = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-duration = -1
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: use-buffering = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: download = false
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: uri = udp://0.0.0.0:6038
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: connection-speed = 0
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: source = "\(GstUDPSrc\)\ source"
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream
/GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream
0:01:19.923679000  3202 0x7f9639857320 WARN               h264parse gsth264parse.c:1351:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame:<h264parse0> broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 16113 will be dropped
0:01:19.924320000  3202 0x7f9639857320 WARN               h264parse gsth264parse.c:1351:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame:<h264parse0> broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 17237 will be dropped
0:01:19.925063000  3202 0x7f9639857320 WARN       codecparsers_h264 gsth264parser.c:2039:gst_h264_parse_pps: failed to read SE
0:01:19.925075000  3202 0x7f9639857320 WARN       codecparsers_h264 gsth264parser.c:2046:gst_h264_parse_pps: error parsing "Picture parameter set"
0:01:19.925081000  3202 0x7f9639857320 WARN               h264parse gsth264parse.c:882:gst_h264_parse_process_nal:<h264parse0> failed to parse PPS:
0:01:19.925089000  3202 0x7f9639857320 WARN               h264parse gsth264parse.c:1351:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame:<h264parse0> broken/invalid nal Type: 8 PPS, Size: 5 will be dropped
0:01:19.925106000  3202 0x7f9639857320 WARN       codecparsers_h264 gsth264parser.c:2039:gst_h264_parse_pps: failed to read SE
```

I'll try playing around with the options and report back.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to handle raw video in your GStreamer pipeline, even though it should handle H.264 encoded video.  Try something like (command untested):

> gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin2 uri=udp://0.0.0.0:6038

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I tried running the command with `export GST_DEBUG=*:3` and I've updated the answer with the output, it's not _quite_ there yet.

I'll report back if I can get it to work.

Comment: I didn't write it down, but the 0.0.0.0 was meant to be replaced by the sender's IP address.  And after reading in detail the stream info page you linked to, keeping the `skip-first-bytes=2` option seems like a good idea as well.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: And after reading the error messages and the stream info page you linked to in detail, keeping the `skip-first-bytes=2` option is required. But then I don't see a way to actually set this option on the command line when using playbin.  In code, one could connect to the [source-setup](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-playbin.html#GstPlayBin-source-setup) signal, but that is not possible on the command line.

Comment: Since you can't use playbin, you have to start with your original command, but change the caps into H.264 instead of raw video and also adjust the depayloader.  Nevertheless, packet reordering may affect you, a proper solution would involve interpreting the first two bytes of each packet with your own gstreamer source filter.